# Python convert list into Dictionary with key value

Tags: python

I am getting json response from SOLR via PySolr , everything works fine, just that Facet fields are coming in inconsistent format , below is the facet fields

```
LocalityId = [ "14008",1,"14293",4,]
```

Now I need to convert the above list into Key-Value pair (Dictionary), likewise

```
LocalityId = {"14008":"1", "14293":"4"}
```

How to achieve this with python ?

Edit : Yes I know its not standard list format , but I didnt created it , blame solr

Edit : Why -1 , stackoverflow has become a place for revenge and random outburst! tell me here folk where I am wrong ??

Comment: i didn't find a list like  above.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yep same here, but this the standard solr response with or without PySolr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your original list is named `fields`:

```py
dict(zip(fields[::2], map(str, fields[1::2])))
```

**Step by step:**
From the original list `fields` we want the items at even indexes to be the keys and items at odd indexes to be the values.

We will use Python's extending indexing (which is actually the [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) builtin under the hood) to obtain all even and odd indexed items:

```py
>>> list(range(10)[::2])
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> list(range(10)[1::2])
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

The even items are obtained by starting at index `0` (omitted since it's the default) up until the last element (omitted as well) and we will use a step of `2`. For odd items we do the same but starting at index `1`.

If we [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) those two lists together we obtain a list of `(key, value)` that we can pass the return value to the [dict constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Now we only need to make the values `str`s to match the desired output, for that we will use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
>>> even_items = fields[::2]
>>> odd_items = fields[1::2]
>>> key_value_pairs = zip(even_items, odd_items)
>>> dict(key_value_pairs)
{'14008': 1, '14293': 4}
```

Or in one line:

```py
dict(zip(fields[::2], map(str, fields[1::2])))
```

Comment: Might add a `map(str, ....)` to the second part to exactly match the desired result.

Comment: @A-NirVaan Bro, please add the exact input at very first.

Comment: One quick question, how to do it for n number of elements ? loop ?

Comment: Slicing works for list of any size `range(100)[::2]` will return every even number between `0` and `99`. But maybe that's not what you're asking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) for convert to your list to expected dictionary  :

```
>>> l=[ "14008",1,"14293",4,]
>>> dict(zip(l[::2],l[1::2]))
{'14008': 1, '14293': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use dict comprehension.

```
l = ["14008", 1, "14293", 4]
{l[i*2]: l[i*2+1] for i in range(int(len(l)/2))}
```

Comment: Thanks Mika ji , really appreeciate