# Converting a list into a dictionary with key value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a python list that is in the form

```
scores = [' "abc":1, "xyz":"2", "def":3 ']
```

I need to convert this to a python dictionary so that the dictionary elements are extracted using the key.

```
scores_dict = { "abc":1, "xyz":"2", "def":3 }
```

I'd like to be able to extract scores_dict["abc"] = 1 etc.

I've referred to the link below and tried a few examples but I am stuck:

[Python convert list into Dictionary with key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987480/python-convert-list-into-dictionary-with-key-value)

```
scores_dict = dict.fromkeys(scores, 1)
print(scores_dict["abc"])

dict_comp = {k.strip():v.strip() for k,v in zip(scores[0].split(','), scores[1].split(','))}
print(dict_comp)

def score_parser(scores):
    row = scores.split(',')
    network.append(row)
    return network
```

Comment: Oddly specific input, isn't it.

Comment: You really have a list with a single string inside? That wasn't a typo?

Comment: just an example , actual list is totally different - yes ,a string within a string.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so what you want to do is go thought the whole list and separate key from value, then you will add it to the dictionary

```
scores_dict = {}
for thing in scores:
    thing = thing.split(":")
    key = thing[0]
    value = thing[1]
    scores_dict[key] = value
print(scores_dict)
```

If it doesnt work, let me know ( i typed it on the phone so i hope its good )

Comment: It looks like `2` should be a string, but `1` and `3` should be ints. This solution makes them all strings, and `2` has quotes in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json`:

```
import json

scores = [' "abc":1, "xyz":"2", "def":3 ']

scores_dict = json.loads('{' + scores[0] + '}')
```

Output:

```
{'abc': 1, 'xyz': '2', 'def': 3}
```

Comment: Json is really good choice :) I would recommand this over my answer

Comment: And `fromkeys` can only assign single value to all keys.

Comment: @nlp If this answer worked for you, be sure to accept it for future viewers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your list like this:

```
scores = [["abc", 1], ["xyz", 2], ["def", 3]]
```

You will be able to use dict()

```
dict_scores = dict(scores)
```